# With Microsoft 365 SSO. Delete user in third-party App when such user gets deleted in Active Directory

Tags: entra-id, single-sign-on

I have an application connected to Microsoft Active Directory using SSO. So basically users in the third-party App authenticate with Microsoft 365 using SSO however we would like to delete a user in the third-party app when such user gets deleted from our Active Directory.

Is this possible? Where could we find some documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably if your 3rd party app is having some API, you can sync when deleting an AD user to do it also to your 3rd party app. You could try

Comment: Excellent thanks. That's what I wanted to know.